# to upload two(photo and signature) image only in database from one page using c#

Tags: c#-3.0

There is a page where I've to upload and view photo and signature (the snapshot of the page is attached )but whenever i click the view button the path to the image gets clear and the binary format of the image is saved something like 0x(only this much is saved in database nothing else) format in the database .And the 2nd thing is that both photo and signature are to be seen individually without saving in database.please suggest me a solution for this please.

code

protected void pichck()
    {
        string picextension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(imgflup.PostedFile.FileName.ToString()).ToLower();
        fs = imgflup.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        picbyte = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
        byte[] picarray=new byte[]{255,216,255};
        //Boolean match = true;
        //int i;
        //for (i = 0; i <= picarray.Length - 1;i=i+1 )
        //{
        //    if(picarray[i]!=picbyte[i])
        //    {
        //        match = false;
        //        break;
        //    }
        //}
        //if (match == true)
        //{
        if (picextension == ".jpg" || picextension == ".jpeg")
        {
            if (imgflup.HasFile == true)
            {
                if (imgflup.PostedFile.ContentLength < 20000 & imgflup.PostedFile.ContentLength > 50000)
                {

```
                Response.Write("<script>alert('the file should be of size 20 mb to 50mb ')</script>");
                check();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(picbyte, 0, picbyte.Length);

                picimg.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
                Label1.Visible = true;
                Label1.Visible = true;
                Label1.Text = imgflup.PostedFile.FileName;
            }
        }
        //}
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('the file should be of jpg or jpeg format')</script>");
            check();
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please Upload a file')</script>");
        check();
        return;
    }
}
protected void signchckt()
{
    string signextension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(signflup.PostedFile.FileName.ToString()).ToLower();
    fs1 = signflup.PostedFile.InputStream;
    BinaryReader br1 = new BinaryReader(fs1);
    signbyte = br1.ReadBytes((Int32)fs1.Length);
    //Boolean match = true;
    //int i;
    //byte[] signarray=new byte[]{255,216,255};
    //for (i = 0; i <= signarray.Length - 1;i=i+1 )
    //{
    //    if(signarray[i]!=signbyte[i])
    //    {
    //        match = false;
    //        break;
    //    }
    //}
        //if (match == true)
        //{
            if (signflup.HasFile == true)
            {
                if (signextension == ".jpg" || signextension == ".jpeg")
                {

                    if (signflup.PostedFile.ContentLength < 20000 & signflup.PostedFile.ContentLength > 50000)
                    {

                    Response.Write("<script>alert('the file should be of size 20 mb to 50mb ')</script>");
                    check1();
                    return;
                     }
                else
                     {
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(signbyte, 0, signbyte.Length);
                    signimg.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
                    Label2.Visible = true;
                                            Label2.Visible = true;
                                            Label2.Text =signflup.PostedFile.FileName;

                     }
               }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('The signature should be of jpg or jpeg type')</script>");
                    check1();
                    return;
                }
            }
        //}
        else
        {

        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please Upload a file')</script>");
        check1();
        return;

        }
    }


protected void imgviewbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pichck();
}
protected void signviewbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    signchckt();
}
protected void updtbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int64 aplicationid = Convert.ToInt64(Session["ID"].ToString());
    if (Session["ID"].ToString()=="")
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('There is no Application Id')</script>");
        Response.Redirect("~/home.aspx");
    }
    else
    {

    using (obj.con)
    {
        pichck();
        signchckt();
        obj.con.Open();
        obj.cmd = new SqlCommand("spPhotoandsignature",obj.con);
        obj.cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        obj.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Application_Id", aplicationid);
        obj.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pic_Scan",SqlDbType.Binary).Value =picbyte;
        obj.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pic_Size", fs);
        obj.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sign_Scan",SqlDbType.Binary).Value =signbyte;
        obj.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sign_Size", fs1);
        obj.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", System.IO.Path.GetExtension(imgflup.PostedFile.FileName.ToString()).ToLower());

           int a= obj.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           if (a == 1)
           {

               Response.Write("<script>alert('your data Submitted successfully')</script>");

               Response.Redirect("~/Report.aspx");
           }
    }
    }
}
```

[problempage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk6hc.png).png

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.  This question seems fairly broad at this point.

Comment: i've attached the code